# Resources for learning fixed point logic

Tags: reference-request, logic

As the title says, I am looking for resources to learn some fixed point logic, especially partial fixed point logic. I have basic knowledge of propositional calculus and predicate logic, but sadly not much beyond that, and have need of PFP for my bachelor's thesis. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can see Heinz-Dieter Ebbinghaus & Jörg Flum, [Finite Model Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=jIFpliJXCw8C&pg=PA119) (2nd ed 1999), **7. Descriptive Complexity Theory**, page 119-on

Comment: If you don't have any luck here, you might want to try the Philosophy StackExchange.