# Reference request: equivalence between formulas in fixed point and first-order logic

Tags: reference-request, logic, fixed-point-theorems

I'm looking for materials on the relationship between first-order and fixed-point logics, specifically on the condition for a formula in some sort of fixed-point logic to have an equivalent first-order formula.

Note that [a recent post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1369806/resources-for-learning-fixed-point-logic) had a comment that introduced a textbook specifically on finite models.  On the other hand I am interested in models that are not necessarily finite, and the specific relationship between first-order and fixed-point logics as stated above.